# How to use tryCatch in a nested loop to print step numbers of error and warnings?

Tags: r, for-loop, try-catch, nested-loops

I have found several posts related to this issue however I just wasted my time!

I have a nested for loop (2 loops) in R. Within the inner loop sometimes **error** occurs and sometimes **warnings**. But the code runs for the whole iteration. So I don't find the steps where those occurred.

I want to find out using `tryCatch` in which steps those occur i.e., **iteration numbers**.

As I have a big data file (almost with 3000 row), so it is difficult to find them manually.

Here, is a similar reproducible code:

```
flist= seq(2,14,3)
res=NULL

for(j in 1:length(flist))
{
ff=flist[j]
msave=NULL

for(i in 1:50)
{
run1 = ff/0.0009 #here error or warnings occur#
run2 = run1/i
minus=run1-run2
msave=c(msave,minus)
}

res=c(res,mean(msave))
}
```

Please suggest me how can I edit this code with `tryCatch`.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

based on the detail section of `help(tryCatch)`:

```
flist= seq(2,14,3)
res=NULL

for(j in 1:length(flist))
{
  # Catch outer loop
  tryCatch(
    {
      ff=flist[j]
      msave=NULL
      
      for(i in 1:50)
      {
        # catch inner loop
        tryCatch(
          {
            run1 = ff/0.0009 #here error or warnings occur#
            run2 = run1/i
            minus=run1-run2
            msave=c(msave,minus)
          },
          # Error catcher for inner loop
          error = function(err){
            print(paste(j, i))
          },
          # evaluated after inner "error"
          finally = function(fin)invisible()
        )
      }
      res=c(res,mean(msave))
    },
    # error catcher for outer loop
    error = function(err){
      print(j)
    },
    # Evalauted after outer "error"
    finally = function(fin)invisible()
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks I think your code works!

Comment: But it doesn't show whether I got an error or warnings. Is it possible to know?

Comment: Sure thing, add `, warning = function(warn) { print('i got a warning')}` somewhere in tryCatch (edit function your needs). Generally speaking, `error = function(x)` will catch errors, `warning = function(x)` will catch warnings and `finally = function(x)` will run after every handler (handlers are error and warning handlers for example). Note that the input to the function, is the error/warning message itself. So error = function(err)simpleError(err)` would simply send the error message. So you could first do something and then re-throw the error using that method.

Comment: Thanks I realized this just after posting my comment.